# Scala why flatMap treats (x => x) different than (identity)

Tags: scala, flatmap

First, `map` treats `x => x` identical than `identity`

```
List(1,2,3).map(x => x)   //res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
List(1,2,3).map(identity) //res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Now let's transform a List[Option[Int]] into List[Int] discarding all None. We can do that by `.flatten`. But the point of this question is to understand how `flatMap` treats `identity`

```
val maybeNums = List(Some(1), None, Some(-2), None, None, Some(33))

// Works OK, result = List[Int] = List(1, -2, 33)
maybeNums.flatMap(x => x)
maybeNums.flatMap(x => x.map(identity))

// Not working:
maybeNums.flatMap(identity)

Error:(5, 20) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Int] => Option[Int]
 required: Option[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

**Question**: why does `maybeNums.flatMap(identity)` give a compilation error while `maybeNums.flatMap(x => x)` works OK?

Comment: I'm guessing the answer will somehow involve eta-expansion and how partially applied methods are typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more detailed explanation of Lampart's answer.

It comes down to how type inference works in Scala and use of expected types.

For `maybeNums.flatMap(???)` to work, `???` must have type `Option[Int] => GenTraversableOnce[?A]` (where `?A` stands for some unknown type). That's the expected type.

When `???` is a lambda expression like `x => x`, the argument is typed as `Option[Int]` and the body is typed with the expected type `GenTraversableOnce[?A]`. The type of the body *without* expected type is `Option[Int]`, so the implicit conversion from `Option[Int]` to `GenTraversableOnce[Int]` is found and inserted.

When `???` is `identity`, it's short for `identity[?B]` for some yet unknown type `?B` (in the same sense as `?A` above, but they don't have to be the same, of course), and so has type `?B => ?B`. So the compiler needs to solve an equation with two unknown types: `?B => ?B == Option[Int] => GenTraversableOnce[?A]`. It matches argument types to pick `?B = Option[Int]` for `?B`, but can't find a suitable `?A`. When the error is printed, `?B` is substituted and the type which I wrote as `?A` above is printed as `?` (because it's the only remaining unknown).

In case `identity(_)`, it's expanded to `x => identity(x)`. Again, the type of the argument is inferred to be `Option[Int]` and the body has calculated type `Option[Int]` and expected type `GenTraversableOnce[?A]`.

Comment: Wonderful explanation, thanks. Can you please elaborate more on "When `???` is `identity`, it has type `A => A` for some `A`" ? Why only some A and not all kinds of A? Does that mean there could be something which can not be itself? (naive literal interpretation of `identity`)

Comment: @Polymerase I've edited the answer a bit for more consistent terminology, hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 4):

Funny thing i had a similar problem to yours. This behavior is caused by the fact that `Option` is not `GenTraversableOnce` but there exists an implicit conversion to one. Compiler informs you what is wrong, but unfortunately as it is the case frequently in Scala it does not point the real reason of a mistake. If your collection was containing elements of `GenTraversableOnce` type, flatMap method would work just fine.

At first i thought that implicit conversion would solve this problem, but it turns out that eta expansion needs types to match explicitly. What's more interesting is that the following code compiles:

```
ys.flatMap(identity(_))
```

I assume that in this case implicit conversion from `Option[Int] => Option[Int]` to `Option[Int] => GenTraversableOnce[Int]` happens.

In the case of `x => x` right `x` is converted with the previously mentioned implicit conversion so the code compiles

Comment: I explained the `identity(_)` case in my answer. There's no implicit conversion from `Option[Int] => Option[Int]` to `Option[Int] => GenTraversableOnce[Int]` there, if there were, `flatMap(identity)` would work as well.