# Scala why flatMap treats (identity[Option[Int]]) different than (identity)

Tags: scala

Talking about Scala 2.12.8.

I got an error on `Seq(Some(1), None).flatMap(identity)` and found existing question.

> [Scala why flatMap treats (x => x) different than (identity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383152/scala-why-flatmap-treats-x-x-different-than-identity)

**Another Question:** Why the second one is ok? If any implicit conversion is applied, why the conversion is not applicable to first one?

```scala
scala> Seq(Some(1), None).flatMap(identity)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Int] => Option[Int]
 required: Option[Int] => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
       Seq(Some(1), None).flatMap(identity)
                                  ^

scala> Seq(Some(1), None).flatMap(identity[Option[Int]])
res2: Seq[Int] = List(1)
```

My thoughts is that `identity[Option[Int]]` has a type `Option[Int] => Option[Int]` and cannot be `Option[Int] => GenTraversableOnce[Int]` implicitly...

Comment: Besause of conversion from Option and GenTraversableOnce come from implicit converison optionToIterable

Comment: Why the implicit conversion works on `identity[Option[Int]]` and not on `identity` ?

Comment: Maybe it cannot infer to type of `None` properly. Try `Option.empty[Int]` instead. What is your Scala version? Your original example works fine for me on 2.13.0.

Comment: But why you not to use `flatten` method on Seq?

Comment: @Thilo It's on 2.12.8 as written. 2.13 introduced new trait `IterableOnce` and no interesting(or strange) things happen on `flatMap`.
Identical result on `None` vs `Option.empty[Int]`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/G5uyYAZOSnutAHENvJ1DsA